# Redirect customer to the different page after submitting for account creation error

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, shopify

i am able to redirect user to the different page when "create" label is clicked. But the problem is when I enable the following code for redirecting

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var REDIRECT_PATH = '/pages/become-a-partner-submit';

    var selector = '#create_customer, form[action$="/account"][method="post"]',
        $form = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0];

    if ($form) {
      $redirect = document.createElement('input');
      $redirect.setAttribute('name', 'return_to');
      $redirect.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      $redirect.value = REDIRECT_PATH;
      $form.appendChild($redirect);
    }
  })();
</script>
```

The parameters for form error is not working for example if the password value is empty and if user clicks "create" account it stills redirecting the page to the path. When i disable that javascript code its works fine it wont allowed users to create account if the password or others areas are empty. So how can i have a still run the form error parameters and and redirect customer to the link after account creation ?

Heres my full code.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LeJp8EgAAAAAN2IymRMhGeete2PDs2hOsRHCWvB"></script>

<div class="central py-medium" id="template">
  <div id="customer">
    <!-- Create Customer -->
    <div id="create-customer">
      <div class="template_header">
        <h1 class="h2 feature-header" data-cc-animate>{{ 'customer.register.title' | t }}</h1>
      </div>


      
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            
          <h6>Need Assistance ?</h6>
          <p class="needAssistance"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

      
      {% form 'create_customer' %}

   
    
      <div data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.2s">
        {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
      </div>


      
      <div class="form">
        <div class="input-row" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.2s">
          <input aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}" type="text" value="" name="customer[first_name]" id="first_name" class="large" size="30" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-row" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.35s">
          <input aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}" type="text" value="" name="customer[last_name]" id="last_name" class="large" size="30" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-row" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.5s">
          <input aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}" type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="email" class="large" size="30" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-row" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.65s">
          <input aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}" type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="password" class="large password" size="30" />
        </div>

        <div class="wide-action">
          <input type="submit" value="{{ 'customer.register.submit' | t }}" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.8s"/>
          
          <a href="https://arditicollection.com/account/login?return_url=%2Faccount">
          <p style="padding-bottom:5px;">Back to Login Page</p>
          </a>
          
          <span class="note" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.95s">
            <a data-cc-animate-click href="{{ routes.root_url }}">
              {{ 'customer.register.cancel' | t }}
            </a>
          </span>
        
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endform %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script>
    function onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
                callCommentAPI(token);
            });
        });
    }
</script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arr = ['1 786 633 19 38', '1 786 633 12 98', '1 786 633 19 03'];      
   //console.log(arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]);
    let randArr = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
      let callus = 'Call us <a class="callUsLoginPage" href="tel:+'+randArr+'">+'+randArr+'</a> or email us at <a class="needAssistanceEmail" href="mailto:contact@arditicollection.com">contact@arditicollection.com</a>';
        $('.needAssistance').html(callus);
});
    </script>



{% comment %}
<script>
  (function() {
    var REDIRECT_PATH = '/pages/become-a-partner-submit';

    var selector = '#create_customer, form[action$="/account"][method="post"]',
        $form = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0];

    if ($form) {
      $redirect = document.createElement('input');
      $redirect.setAttribute('name', 'return_to');
      $redirect.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      $redirect.value = REDIRECT_PATH;
      $form.appendChild($redirect);
    }
  })();
</script>

{% endcomment %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Adding following code under the `{% 'create_customer' %}` form.

```
<div class ="errors"> </div>
```

Add the following script to and change the url as you like.

```
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
jQuery('#create_customer').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = jQuery(this).serialize();

 //create new account
  jQuery.post('/account', data)
    .done(function(data){
    var logErrors = jQuery(data).find('.errors').text();

    //if there are errors show them in the html form
    if (logErrors != "" && logErrors != 'undefined'){
        jQuery('#create_customer .errors').html(logErrors);
        jQuery('#create_customer .errors').show();

    //if account creation is successful show checkout page
    }else{
       console.log('success');
      document.location.href = 'CHANGE URL';
    }
    }).fail(function(){console.log('error');});
   return false;
}); 
});
</script>
```

Heres the full code

```
    {% form 'create_customer'%}
        
      <div class ="errors"> </div>
      
      {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
      <div class="form">
        <div class="input-row" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.2s">
          <input aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}" type="text" value="" name="customer[first_name]" id="first_name" class="large" size="30" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-row" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.35s">
          <input aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}" type="text" value="" name="customer[last_name]" id="last_name" class="large" size="30" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-row" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.5s">
          <input aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}" type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="email" class="large" size="30" />
        </div>

        <div class="input-row" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.65s">
          <input aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}" type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="password" class="large password" size="30" />
        </div>

        <div class="wide-action">
          <input type="submit" value="{{ 'customer.register.submit' | t }}" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.8s"/>
          
          <a href="https://arditicollection.com/account/login?return_url=%2Faccount">
          <p style="padding-bottom:5px;">Back to Login Page</p>
          </a>
          
          <span class="note" data-cc-animate data-cc-animate-delay="0.95s">
            <a data-cc-animate-click href="{{ routes.root_url }}">
              {{ 'customer.register.cancel' | t }}
            </a>
          </span>
        
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endform %}


<script>
  jQuery(function() {
jQuery('#create_customer').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = jQuery(this).serialize();

 //create new account
  jQuery.post('/account', data)
    .done(function(data){
    var logErrors = jQuery(data).find('.errors').text();

    //if there are errors show them in the html form
    if (logErrors != "" && logErrors != 'undefined'){
        jQuery('#create_customer .errors').html(logErrors);
        jQuery('#create_customer .errors').show();

    //if account creation is successful show checkout page
    }else{
       console.log('success');
      document.location.href = '/pages/create-account-submit';
    }
    }).fail(function(){console.log('error');});
   return false;
}); 
});
</script>
```